# Dependent drop down of Country,City in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu, search-box

how can ı do dependent drop down search box country and city in Codeigniter 
ı do dependent but my searcbox  not found list in searchbox dynamic data

ı have two dropdown menu country and city dropdownlist when on select country list city but ı want search box country and dropdown and select multiple city box with search box

Comment: Please elaborate what you have tried.

Comment: ı have two dropdown menu country and city dropdownlist when on select country list city but ı want search box country and dropdown and select multiple city box with search box

Comment: With this information I can only say that, you render select box in html with country options loaded and on "change" event of country select box, you should run ajax call to server to pull cities for the selected country, then render the list to the next city select box.

Comment: You should add description to your question about which JS lib you are trying, what html markup you are using, what codeigniter code you have you have at backend in context to the question.